# Boost::regex_match isn't firing

Tags: c++, regex, boost

I have some boost Regex code which I think should fire. I'm new to boost but I know a little bit of Regex. Here's the code that I'm using.

```
re = boost::basic_regex<TCHAR>(_T("-+\\s+Original\\s+Message\\s+-+"), boost::regex_constants::icase);
boost::match_results<TSTRING::const_iterator> result;
if(boost::regex_match(RawBody, result, re))
```

and here is the test string I'm using.

```
this is a test

-------- Original Message --------

everything under here should disappear
```

My code compiles and runs, it just doesn't trigger the if statement. I tried debugging into the boost code and ... yeah...

Comment: Use regex_search instead of regex_match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

regex_match

> The algorithm regex_match **determines whether a given regular
>   expression matches all of a given character sequence denoted by a pair
>   of bidirectional-iterators**, the algorithm is defined as follows, the
>   main use of this function is data input validation.

regex_search

> The algorithm regex_search **will search a range denoted by a pair of
>   bidirectional-iterators for a given regular expression.** The algorithm
>   uses various heuristics to reduce the search time by only checking for
>   a match if a match could conceivably start at that position. The
>   algorithm is defined as follows:

So, use `boost::regex_search`. Example.

http://liveworkspace.org/code/fa35778995c4bd1e191c785671ab94b6